# Update only time in a SQL Server DateTime column from another DateTime column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains two `DateTime` columns. I would like to update my table so that it would copy the time only from column A and update that time only in column B without changing the actual date itself. Here is my data:

```
Column A                   | Column B
---------------------------+-------------------------
2017-07-07 16:30:00.000    | 2017-08-30 22:05:00.000
```

The desired output is:

```
Column A                  | Column B
--------------------------+------------------------
2017-07-07 16:30:00.000   | 2017-08-30 16:30:00.000
```

I tried to get this done but I cannot figure out the correct syntax or if it is even possible. Thank you all in advance for your help and direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the time from `a` to `b` after truncating the time portion of `b`:

```
select 
    a
  , b = dateadd(second,datediff(second,convert(date,a),a),convert(datetime,convert(date,b)))
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IRTP42230

returns:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|          a          |          b          |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2017-07-07 16:30:00 | 2017-08-30 16:30:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @SqlZim, your answer did the trick and was AWESOME. Very professional and slick! thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Once quick option is

```
Update YourTable
   set [Column B] = cast(cast([Column B] as date) as datetime)+cast(cast([Column A] as time) as datetime)
```